# Выполнение скрипта со второй страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Есть скрипт модального окна. Скрипт выполняется сразу же как посетитель открыл первую страницу сайта, т.е. когда только зашел на сайт. Скажите, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся когда посетитель открыл уже вторую/следующую страницу сайта, чтобы скрипт определил, что посетитель перешел с домена [http://сайт.рф](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84) и только тогда дал команду на выполнение? Насколько это возможно и сложно? Прошу прощения за каламбур, но как-то так. Вот пример кода, который должен выполниться при таком условии:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (typeof $.cookie('open_login') === 'undefined') { 
    var date = new Date();
    var period = 3;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + period * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $.cookie('open_login', 'yes', {
    expires: date,
    path: '/'
    });
var delay = 30;
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
$('.open_login').trigger('click');
}, delay * 1000);
$('.open_login').one('click', function() {
clearTimeout(timeoutId)
})
    }
});
```

Comment: смотрите `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

Вот мне подсказали (спасибо Dilettante_Pro и j0hnik). Проверил, работает.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   if(document.referrer.indexOf('http://сайт.рф') >= 0){
    // код
   };
});
```